# Money deducted without Verified By Visa authentication

Tags: india, debit-card, online-payment, visa

I am an Indian who has a MNC Bank Visa debit card. I always use Verified By Visa service to pay using my debit card. Last day as usual i entered the details of card in an International Site(I have never bought from an International Site before). However i wasn't redirected to the VBV page, but the money is debited from my account. I was stunned because i wasn't looking to buy it, but seeing how much it costs. (I entered the details because they sent me a coupon and I was trying to redeem it but i haven't seen the space to enter coupon code anywhere. So i thought i will just enter card details and see what happens.) How is this possible?
Am i able for a refund since the transaction took place without my authorization ?

Here is another point: This is the site https://www.underarmour.com/en-in . Can this be considered as an Indian Site cause it have "en-in" in the URL and the price shown is Indian rupees ? If so then they must follow RBI standards which they did not.

There are other sites like this. eg: http://www.mi.com/in  which are Indian.

This is the Reserve Bank Statement: "Further, to reduce the risks arising out of the use of credit/debit cards over internet/IVR (technically referred to as card not present (CNP) transactions), Reserve Bank mandated that all CNP transactions should be additionally authenticated based on information not available on the card and an online alert should be sent to the cardholders for such transactions."

**In that case my transaction is not authorized.**

What is your opinion ?

Update: I somehow managed to cancel the order and got refund from merchant.

Comment: `sent me a coupon and I was trying to redeem it but i haven't seen the space to enter coupon code` Then why did you proceed to pay ? `Verified By Visa` doesn't come up unless you are ready to pay.

Comment: Using VbV is not *your* choice; its presence on a particular site is a decision negotiated between the website and the card scheme. For example, Amazon doesn't use it...

Comment: Contact the international website ASAP and request for them to cancel the order. If they have not shipped it yet then there should be no issues.

Comment: _"i thought i will just enter card details and see what happens"_ I.. what?

Comment: _"the transaction took place without my authorization ?"_ No, it didn't.

Comment: In sites like Amazon India, you get to enter card details first and then you click on submit. Then you are redirected to Verify By Visa site where you enter password. Almost all sites in India works like this. I did it from my experience.

Comment: I tried a cancellation but they have already sent the product. If i return it they will refund the amount. I paid nearly 2000 as customs duty, so if i return it, will I get the full amount or (full amount - customs duty) ?

Comment: So since they canceled the order and issued a refund, then I guess they didn't really "already sent the product" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Indian cards Verified by visa comes only for Indian sites as RBI has mandated by regulation. However foreign sites need not be governed by Indian laws.

Depending on the site you can request for cancellation and get a refund.

If you dispute with your card issuer, it would be very difficult to explain what you have said.

***Edits***:

> Can this be considered as an Indian Site cause it have "en-in" in the URL and the price shown is Indian rupees ?

Domain name has got nothing to do with company being in India or prices listed in Rupees. A company must be incorporated in India and must provide services in India.

> In that case my transaction is not authorized.

There are different types / mechanism of authorizations. I have just given my card number with expiry on telephone and got my card charged. Of course I trusted the organization. However I can't go back to Card Issuer and dispute saying this is invalid transaction as no VBV was used.

In your case you have entered all details and clicked pay. So it would be difficult for you to prove that you did not do the said actions. Further the item was dispatched to your address. So there is no malpractice on the online merchant.

Comment: Right.  Folks in India are used to ALWAYS seeing VBV.  It's simply not the case outside of Indi.

Comment: And those of us outside India are used to refusing/opting-out of VbV when a site tries to use it because it's snake oil, bad security UX, and shifts liability off the merchant and card issuer and onto the cardholder.

Comment: Many merchants I use employ VbV, but for the past several years it always auto-authorises because I am on the same hardware, at the same IP... somehow relying on a VbV prompt to make sure you don't accidentally buy something is absurd!

Comment: @R.. I've never used VBV -- can you explain how liability shifts? I understand this might be a country-specific question, so if you just want to speak relative to your own country that's fine too.

Comment: @JohnFeminella: It's additional "evidence that you authorized the transaction". This is problematic if you didn't authorize it at all (e.g. someone got your card number and passwords via a keylogger or other malware) or if you accidentally authorize a transaction in duplicate etc. Additional evidence of authorization **always works against the cardholder**.

Comment: I tried a cancellation but they have already sent the product. If i return it they can refund the amount. I paid nearly 2000 as customs duty, so if i return it, will I get the full amount or (full amount - customs duty) ?

Comment: @JithinSebastian What you paid as customs duty, you will have to recover from customs. Generally not worth the effort.

Comment: I think it is better for me to keep it then.
I have edited the question. Can you take a look at it please ?

Comment: @Dheer but as an Indian customer, i will expect to see VBV. So it's not entirely my fault, is it?
Any way,  I'm waiting to see what happens.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I've seen this on poorly designed websites (no reflection on the `underarmour.com` website, since I haven't visited their website) where in order to see the full final charges/cost, including taxes and shipping, you have to enter all the details including payment method with card number. Then you will see the final price with a button to confirm/complete the transaction.

Answer (score 3):

It is up to the merchant whether to use Verified by Visa or not. It saves them transaction fees and sometimes their bank requires it. A lot of sites only require card number, expiration date and CVC to charge the card. Sometimes card number alone is enough, but that is rare in my experience.

Comment: I tried a cancellation but they have already sent the product. If i return it they can refund the amount. I paid nearly 2000 as customs duty, so if i return it, will I get the full amount or (full amount - customs duty) ?